# Lemma about primeness of Gaussian integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, gaussian-integers

I don't understand the proof of this lemma:

> Let $p>1$ be an integer prime number. If $p$ is not prime gaussian integer then $p=\pi\bar{\pi}$ where $\pi$ and $\bar{\pi}$ are prime and conjugate in Gaussian integers.

**Proof:**
Every $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ prime integer is not invertible in $Z[i]$. If $p$ is not a prime gaussian integer then there exists $\pi \in Z[i]$ prime in $Z[i]$ that divide $p$. So $\pi\bar{\pi}$ divide $p^{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ so $\pi\bar{\pi} = p$. Why? I know that $\pi\bar{\pi}$ can be equal to $p^{2}$ or to $p$ or to 1. I don't know why can I say that $\pi\bar{\pi} = p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, obviously, $\pi\overline{\pi} \neq 1$. Second, if $\pi\overline{\pi}=p^2$, then, taking modules, you find $|\pi|=p$, thus $p/\pi$ is a Gaussian integer of modulus one, so is a unit, and $p$ is a Gaussian prime.

Comment: Why $p/\pi$ is a gaussian integers and how you can say that  $p/\pi$ has modulus one?

Comment: Because $|p/\pi|^2=p^2/(\pi\overline{\pi})=1$, and because you just said that $\pi$ divided $p$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Now i understand it